# How to extracted 3d models from CIE RGB space

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, 3d-modelling, assimp

I have a lengthy hexadecimal string data,The data contents are RGB which can stand for X Y Z.Now How can I extracted the 3D model from the RGB color space?OpenCV helps? Or some other library.Now I can come up with a idea.First find the min cube of the colors.Then use scan line to find out the useful points.Then combine the points to surface. Is there a more mature program?

Comment: Your data is a cloud of 3D points (COP). Take a look at PCL: http://pointclouds.org

Comment: @AdiShavit I had used the PCL,PCL offered a fast triangulation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is a cloud of 3D points (COP). The Point Cloud Library - PCL: [pointclouds.org](http://pointclouds.org) offer various tools for processing such data.